# Programmatically Printing PDF file to PDF without PrinterDialog

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am working on a project where I would like to automatically shrink a PDF document by using Microsoft's "Print to PDF" (on Windows 10). While I have had success using 3rd party tools, one of the most important PDF documents routinely to be shrunken contains extensions that prevent it from working as expected through PDFium (chromium?). Thus I am trying to do it without a 3rd party library at this time.

I've had moderate success a few different ways, but the "easiest" still as a few caveats.

This code allows me to open the PDF in Adobe reader, initiate the printing process, and displays the print dialog where users can name and save their file. However, if possible, I would like to do this entirely without the print dialog, since I already have a standardized naming convention and do not want the user to need to interact with the dialog for each of the multiple files being converted.

```
    Sub printme() handles button1.click
    Dim info = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\se4118.pdf")
    Dim p As Process

    'Set process setting to be hidden
    info.Verb = "print"
    info.CreateNoWindow = True
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    info.Arguments = "Microsoft Print To PDF"

    'Start hidden process
    p = New Process()
    p.StartInfo = info
    p.Start()
    end sub
```

I have looked into submitting multiple arguments into "info.Arguments", but did not have any success with them. Does anyone have any idea how to initiate this print using a predetermined name scheme without the print dialog being shown? If it is not possible this way, could you recommend another way that could print a PDF to a PDF (using Adobe as a medium or not)? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Does the "printto" verb work for this? [Verbs and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb776883(v=vs.85))

Comment: I do not believe so. Admittedly I'm a bit new to ProcessStartInfo, but changing my code from "print" to "printto" did not print the document. However, it does bypass the actual Print dialog though, so this may be a step in the right direction. I will continue researching the differences and arguments and report here if I find anything definitive.